# Bedeutung von "zwei Mal mehr" versus "drei Mal so viel"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, mathematics, anglicism

Mir begegnet oft die Formulierung "zwei Mal mehr", die ich in den jeweiligen Kontexten für sachlich falsch halte.

Für mein Verständnis bedeutet "zwei Mal mehr" ein dreifaches des Basiswertes (300 %), denn es ist ja um um ein doppeltes mehr. Oft wird mit der Formulierung "zwei Mal mehr" aber nicht 300 % gemeint, sondern 200 %. Früher hat man dazu "drei Mal soviel" gesagt, was logisch ist. Inzwischen höre ich stattdessen "zwei Mal mehr" aber immer öfter.

Was ist denn richtig?
Kommt die "zwei mal mehr"-Formulierung möglicherweise aus dem Englischen und wie wird sie dort gedeutet?

Comment: Meiner Ansicht nach ist "zwei Mal mehr" immer mißverständlich, weshalb ich den Ausdruck vermeide. Inhaltlich gebe ich dir recht: "zwei Mal mehr" ist 300 %, "zwei Mal soviel" ist 200 %, also doppelt.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than

Comment: Ich finde den Ausdruck eigentlich eindeutig. Die Verwendung geht jedoch immer mehr hin zur für mich falschen Bedeutung. Daher meide ich ihn auch

Comment: Haben die Leute früher auch schon falsch gemacht. Eindeutig ist es trotzdem - viele Leute sagen auch 'immer' wenn sie 'oft' und 'nie' wenn sie 'selten' meinen - man kann deswegen seine Sprache auf das Niveau funktionaler Analphabeten zurückschrauben.

Comment: @Gerhardh Du hast recht, das habe ich schlecht formuliert. Ich meinte, der Ausdruck wird oft mißverständlich gebraucht oder verstanden, weshalb ich ihn nicht nutze, sondern andere Formulierungen verwende. Der Ausdruck an sich ist - rein logisch betrachtet -  in der Tat eindeutig.

Comment: Was ist mit "früher" eigentlich gemeint? 2012? 2002? 1985, 1945, 1900, 1800, 1600?

Answer (score 6):

Richtig, "zweimal mehr" bedeutet 300% des Basiswertes, und "zweimal so viel" bedeutet 200% des Basiswertes.

Der Gebrauch von "Zweimal mehr" mit der Bedeutung von 200% des Basiswertes ist schlichtweg falsch. Allerdings wirst du immer wieder Leuten begegnen, die diese Formulierung falsch benutzen, genauso wie die Wörter "als" und "wie" falsch benutzt werden. Wobei hier wenigstens die Bedeutung quasi eindeutig ist: Selbst wenn jemand sagt, "ich bin größer wie du", ist klar, dass er nicht gleich groß ist.

Wenn dir jemand diese Formulierung entgegen bringt, bleibt dir nichts anderes übrig, als entweder vom richtigen Gebrauch auszugehen, oder nachzufragen.

<sub><sup>Übrigens: Dein großschreiben von "mal/Mal" hat mich dazu gebracht die richtige Gebrauchsweise herauszufinden. Dabei erfuhr ich, dass deine Schreibweise nicht dem Standard entspricht, allerdings zur Betonung genutzt werden kann. Mehr dazu [hier.](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/malMal)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

Das "mehr" muss eigentlich "mehr als" heißen und bezieht sich auf den Basiswert. Zweimal mehr bedeutet 300% des Basiswerts ist also richtig.

Comment: Willkommen bei Deutsche Sprache; die Antwort geht allerdings nicht über bereits Vorhandenes hinaus, weswegen ein Kommentar besser passen würde.

Answer (score -3):

Mehr ist nicht abzählbar.

Zu behaupten:

Richtig, "zweimal mehr" bedeutet 300% des Basiswertes,

ist also falsch.

Comment: Diese Wendung steht in der Regel nicht für sich alleine, sondern in einem Kontext. Man bekommt z.B. _zweimal mehr Gehalt_ im neuen Job. Und das Gehalt (in €/$/¥/£...) ist durchaus abzählbar...

Comment: *In zwei Wochen setzt er zweimal mehr Arbeit zu als in einer Woche, also zweimal mehr Wert, und zugleich vernutzt er zweimal mehr Material von zweimal mehr Wert, und verschleißt zweimal mehr Maschinerie von zweimal mehr Wert, erhält also im Produkt von zwei Wochen zweimal mehr Wert als im Produkt einer Woche.* - ist zwar von einem recht bekannten Autor, aber wenn er *zweimal soviel* geschrieben hätte, wäre es eindeutiger.

Comment: @Takkat Ach daher ging das mit dem realen Sozialismus schief...